# How to make a form to add to join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, join

I have three tables: recipes, scrapbooks and scrapbook_entries.

My scrapbook_entries is a join table containing (:recipe_id and :scrapbook_id)

The recipe and scrapbook already exist and I am trying to make a form which allows the user to select a scrapbook (from current_user.scrapbooks) and then click 'save' which will take the current recipe (form will be in recipe view) and add the scrapbook_id and recipe_id to the scrabook_entries table.

I already have a scrapbook_entries model and controller. My controller looks like this:

```
class ScrapbookEntriesController < ApplicationController

def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.find(params[:recipe_id])
    @scrapbook = current_user.scrapbooks.find(params[:scrapbook_id])
    @entry = current_user.scrapbook_entries.build(scrapbook: @scrapbook)
    if @entry.save
        flash[:success] = "Added '#{@recipe.name}' to scrapbook '#{@scrapbook.name}'"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Could not add to scrapbook"
    end
    redirect_to @recipe
end

end
```

My form within the recipe view looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@scrapbook_entry, :url => scrapbook_entries_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.number_field :scrapbook_id, placeholder: "Scrapbook ID" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, :value => @recipe.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see at the moment the user just has to enter the scrapbook_id he/she wants to save it to. I would eventually like to add a list of scrapbooks in a select field but I have  had trouble with that so any suggestions would be welcomed!

My form currently renders a "Couldn't find Recipe without an ID" error in the controller once I click submit. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

scrapbook.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :recipes, through: :scrapbook_entries
has_many :scrapbook_entries
```

recipe.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :scrapbooks, through: :scrapbook_entries
```

scrapbook_entry.rb

```
has_one :recipe
has_one :scrapbook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that error because `form_for` places fields in a nested hash within `params`. The key for this nested hash is based on the class name of the the model object. Try this:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:scrapbook_entry][:recipe_id])
```

You'll also get an error on the line `@entry = current_user.scrapbook_entries ...` because `User` is not directly associated with `ScrapbookEntry`. Instead, build the entry from the scrapbook:

```
@entry = @scrapbook.scrapbook_entries.build(recipe: @recipe)
```

Comment: That worked I havegot the recipe ID but I am now getting a "Couldn't find Recipe with id=357 [WHERE "recipes"."user_id" = ?]" error?

Comment: What is the value of `current_user`?

Comment: current_user has a user attached to it if that is what you are asking? Typing in current_user into the errors shell gives me a hash of the signed in user

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the data model. Please see the updated code.

Comment: Perfect that seemed to have registered,  recipe_id and scrapbook_id and User. Thank you! Im just on the last bit now. The @user line now generates a "undefined method `scrapbook_entries' for #<User:0x007f8ff8ecc9f0>" error. I have noting relating to scrapbook_entries in the user.rb. is it necessary to fix this?

Comment: I still seem to get the same answer but for #<Scrapbook:0x007fjeifdd>.

Comment: Make sure `Scrapbook` is related to `ScrapbookEntry`. In scrapbook.rb: `has_many :scrapbook_entries`.

Comment: That seemed to fix it but I am now getting this error: "can't write unknown attribute `scrapbook_entry_id'" I will update my Question with model code. Thank you for all you help!

Comment: All fixed. The problem was actually in my scrapbook_entry.rb. Should have been belongs_to. Accepted your answer as it helped me with my initial problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this

```
<%=f.select(:scrapbook_id, Scrapbook.all.collect {|p| [ p.id, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'scrapbook'})%>
```

and if you can create a proper hash so you do not need to assign everything manually. also i can not see the recipe is getting assigned so  just pass the whole hash like this

```
current_user.scrapbook_entries.build(params[:scrapbook_entry])
```

Comment: Problem with the first line there is that I only want to show the scrapbooks that belong to the current_user. And with the second line of code you suggested, do you mean I should just remove the recipe and scrapbook lines from the controller and just have the entry defined?

Comment: Then wouldn't a current_user.scrapbooks.collect (...) instead solve this issue?

Comment: for first you can change it to <%=f.select(:scrapbook_id, current_user.scrapbooks.collect {|p| [ p.id, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'scrapbook'})%> and yes for second it will be better you should remove the recipe and scrapbook line .

Comment: @NitinJ yes that worked for the display in the form thank you! But if I remove the recipe and scrapbook line, I get an undefined scrapbook_entries on the user line. Jonhab's answer works with getting the ID. See comment for the error I am receiving